# Proper method to update Oracle TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE value in database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am attempting an update to a table with a column of type `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIMEZONE`.

I have tried several methods without success as the way the `TIMESTAMP` is written to the database does not have the offset format such as `-05:00` for USA Eastern Time. It's saved using `AMERICA/NEW_YORK` as the time zone, which causes issues with another application that cannot handle this properly.

CURRENT: `28-NOV-16 10.51.43.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

DESIRED: `28-NOV-16 10.51.43.000000000 AM -05:00`

The many postings here speak mainly to formatting the data when it's retrieved from the database; other examples are described with SqlPlus and not in C#.

```
Using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(......))
{
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.CommandText = "update customer set email_addr = :EMAIL, modified_date= SYSDATE 
    where cust_id = :CUSTID";

        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MODIFIED_DATE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = OracleDate.GetSysDate().ToOracleTimeStamp();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("CUSTID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value =Convert.ToDecimal(Session["ID"]);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have also tried `modified_date=to_timestamp(:modified_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mi:ss')` but this generates exception as not a properly formatted time zone.

What is the proper method to accomplish this in C#? Should a date/timestamp column always be written with a conversion from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did a typo in your code. You specified 2 bind variables but you try to bind 3 values.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.CommandText = "update customer set email_addr = :EMAIL, modified_date= :MODIFIED_DATE
where cust_id = :CUSTID";

conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add("EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtEmail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("MODIFIED_DATE", OracleDbType.TimeStampTZ).Value = OracleDate.GetSysDate().ToOracleTimeStamp();
cmd.Parameters.Add("CUSTID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value =Convert.ToDecimal(Session["ID"]);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`OracleDbType` is not `Varchar2`, it must be `TimeStampTZ`.

However, it looks like you are using Oracle Data Provider from DevArt. When I check the [documentation](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDate_members.html) it looks like they do not support data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

I see several workarounds.

Set your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` to `-05:00` before you run your operations on database, for example as this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-05:00'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then your C# code can be like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.CommandText = "update customer set email_addr = :EMAIL, modified_date= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
where cust_id = :CUSTID";

conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add("EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtEmail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("CUSTID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value =Convert.ToDecimal(Session["ID"]);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions052.htm#SQLRF00629) returns current time in you session time zone as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type.

You can also specify time zone in SQL, example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update customer set email_addr = :EMAIL, 
       modified_date= SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'
   where cust_id = :CUSTID";
```

When you update a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value with `TIMESTAMP` Oracle will make an implicit cast to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` using time zone `-05:00`.

**Note**, America/New_York has Daylight Saving Time, i.e. you must make these commands more dynamic and switch between `-05:00` and `-04:00` twice a year (that would be the great befit if you would use time zone regions like `America/New_York`).

Another workaround could be to run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI:SS.FF AM TZH:TZM'` at your application which cannot handle time zone names like `AMERICA/NEW_YORK`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it also answers another question that I had about setting session parameters. Thank you! BTW when I use SYSTIMESTAMP I get the correct time zone automatically so I didn't actually need to use `AT TIME ZONE`. Thank you again.